# Execute function when post is published

Tags: posts, hooks

I try to use this function i have created when a post is published for the first time.

```
function a_new_post($post){
  $post_id = $post->ID;

  if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'firstpublish', $single = true ) ) {
      // ...run code once
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'firstpublish', true );
  }
}
add_action( 'draft_to_published', 'a_new_post' );
```

I can't see anything wrong with it, but when i try to create some sample posts i check the database and the field "firstpublished" has not been created.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you change the hook to `publish_post`. `draft_to_publish` won't run for all the cases

Comment: I tried `publish_post` and it does not work (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141779/how-to-test-a-blog-post-for-publish-vs-update-status)

Comment: This is the most frustrating thing I have ever dealt with in WordPress. There is absolutely now way to catch publish and block update. Now way, no how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct action is `'draft_to_publish'`.

To be sure you used the correct status try to get a list of all registered post statuses (including custom statuses) with:

```
<pre><?php print '- ' . implode( "\n- ", array_keys( get_post_stati() ) );?></pre>
```

On a vanilla installation you should get:

- publish
- future
- draft
- pending
- private
- trash
- auto-draft
- inherit

Note that `publish_post` is called each time you *edit* a published post.

Note also [`get_post_stati()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_stati/) is one of these unpredictable names in WordPress: it is plain wrong. The plural of the noun *status* is *statuses* in English and *statūs* in Latin. :D

You could also hook into [`'transition_post_status'`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=transition_post_status), depending on your needs. You get the new and the old status as arguments, the third argument is the post object. It will catch `future_to_publish` too, and also posts that were trashed once and republished now (`trash_to_publish`).

Example:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'a_new_post', 10, 3 );

function a_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type )
        return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

    // do something awesome
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post First save Time meta value set so easy to apply on first time.

```
function a_new_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'firstpublish', $single = true ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'firstpublish', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'a_new_post', 10, 3 );
```