# How to access the post meta of a post that has just been published?

Tags: post-meta, publish

I am using the hook `publish_post` to run my code where I need the post meta of the just published post. But the post meta value I am looking for is somehow not available at this point of execution. On checking the `wp_postmeta` table, I found that my meta key value hasn't been created yet. Also, I want this to work for a post published for the first time. Is there any other hook that can give me access to it?

```
function push_notification($post_id) 
{ 
    $ref_ids = get_post_meta($post_id,'ref_id'); 

    if($ref_ids) 
    { 
        //my code goes here 
    } 
} 

add_action('publish_post','push_notification');
```

Comment: Why don't you hook onto `save_post` and check for `post_status` equal to `publish`, i.e `if ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) ..etc` and if you only want to run this function on newly published posts, not re-published/updated posts you could look at `wp_transition_post_status` and check for `$old_status` against `$new_status`

Comment: @toscho The `get_post_meta($post_id,'ref_id')` returns nothing. Therefore, my code is never executed.

Comment: @PoulomiNag Try one of the methods listed [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69802/73) and report back please. It would also be useful to see how you _add_ the post meta value.

Comment: @userabuser Same problem with `save_post`. No post meta available. I should have mentioned before that I want this to work for a post published for the first time. And `save_post` gives access to post meta only at updates.

Comment: @toscho I checked your link. Issue still exists even when I use `transition_post_status` and `draft_to_publish`. And I am adding the post meta from a custom meta box during post creation. No issues with that. The only problem is that post meta is not yet saved in the database when these hooks are run.

Comment: Ok well as I mentioned I think `wp_transition_post_status` if what you want. Take a look @toscho's link because he talks about that function exactly

Comment: How are you setting your `$post_id`? Although it should be available, have you tried globalizing it? `global $post;` then use `$post->ID` ...

Comment: @userabuser `$post` is available alright. Have echoed and checked.

Comment: I tested your code and it works just fine. The problem is elsewhere. That is, the problem is with how and maybe *when* you are setting the 'ref_id' postmeta value. At least one other person has wondered about that code already. Please edit your question to include the code that creates the 'ref_id' value.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thanks for pointing that out.I checked and found the problem. The issue's resolved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it! Used `save_post` to run `push_notification()` as well as to run the function `save_post_meta()` that saves my post meta. The problem occurred coz `push_notification()` gets fired before `save_post_meta()` due to which the meta wasn't being saved and therefore it remained inaccessible. Just changed priorities of the functions to make it work like so :

```
function push_notification($post_id) 
{ 
  $ref_ids = get_post_meta($post_id,'ref_id'); 

  if($ref_ids) 
  { 
    //my code goes here 
   } 
} 
add_action('save_post','push_notification',11,1);

function save_post_meta($post_id,$post)
{
   //check for nonces and current user capabilities

   $ref_id = sanitize_html_class($_POST['ref_id']);
   update_post_meta($post_id,'ref_id',$ref_id);
}
add_action('save_post','save_post_meta',10,2);

function no_notification()
{
  remove_action('save_post','push_notification',11,1);
}
add_action('publish_to_publish','no_notification');
```

The last function `no_notification()` makes sure that `push_notification()` gets fired only when a post is first created and not for updates.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be concerned only with **new** posts (as previously-created posts will have the postmeta attached and available when transitions are run), and want to do push_notification on newly-created posts only if a certain postmeta value is present. Correct?

Create your own hook in the function that saves your postmeta, after all of your update_postmeta calls, using do_action(). The postmeta will have been saved at that point, and you can test.

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed that when you call `get_post_meta()` within `add_action('publish_post',..)` no post meta is returned.

This is because when you publish the post and 'publish_post' is called, **the post meta is not yet saved in the database**. `update_post_meta()` (the function that saves the post meta in the database) is called after 'publish_post'. That's why it works if you save as draft first and then publishes.

To avoid that issue I use this kind of code:

```
$post_meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key',true);
if($post_meta_value==''){ $post_meta_value = $_POST['meta_key']; }
```

This will get your value from the $_POST when you click on Publish button.
The `$_POST['meta_key']` can be different depending on how you set your post meta or custom field in your back-end. I'm using the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin and it would be `$_POST['fields']['field_52fae7b2b4033']`.

Hope that helps.