# How to hook into publish_posttype?

Tags: hooks, publish

I'm trying to hook into WordPress publish.  The code below is what I'm using, but it doesn't appear to be running.  I have it in a plugin file that I deactivate/reactivate each time I make changes (not sure if that's necessary to do that though).  Post type is "auction".

```
add_action( 'publish_auction', 'bvf_set_ceiling_once_on_first_publish' );

function bvf_set_ceiling_once_on_first_publish( $post ) {

    $post_id = $post->ID;

    if ( !get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ceiling', $single = true ) ) {

    $reserve = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'reserve', $single = true );

    $ceiling = $reserve * (rand(40,60) / 100);

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ceiling', $ceiling );

    }
}
```

Now I'm trying the following (01/16/13):

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Bids_Views
 * @version 0.0.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Bids/Views
Description: None
Author: Jerry T.    
Version: 0.0.1
*/

add_action('publish_post', 'bvf_set_ceiling');
function bvf_set_ceiling( $post_id ) {

$post = get_post($post_id);

$reserve = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'reserve', true );

$ceiling = $reserve * (rand(40,60) / 100);

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ceiling', $ceiling );

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

function looks fine, `$single = true` might be causing your problem, replace it with `true`

Comment: Gave that a try, no change.

Comment: Just noticed, I don't think `publish_{post_type}` accepts args, try by declaring `global $post;`.

Answer (score 0):

The function can use as parameter the post id, not the array or object. Check this with a 'var_dump($post); exit;' in the first line of your function.

You can also use the default hook. A small example, but untested, write from scratch on mobile.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'my-function-on-publish');
function my-function-on-publish( $post_id ) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    if ('auction' === $post->post_type ) {
        //My function
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here.  I was under the impression that basically I could throw this into a plugin file and activate that.  The code I just tried to see if it worked at all is above.

Comment: No, your are right here. And yes, you can throw this in a plugin and it should work.

Comment: Still a no go, any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: do you have output via var_dump() in the conditional, it works on save all post type and the conditional check for your post type and update as example the post meta data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you publish the post and 'publish_post' is called, the post meta is not yet saved in the database. update_post_meta() (the function that saves the post meta in the database) is called after 'publish_post'.

See work around here:
[How to access the post meta of a post that has just been published?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69810/how-to-access-the-post-meta-of-a-post-that-has-just-been-published/134283#134283)