# Post Meta Emtpy on Publish Using Transition

Tags: hooks, publish

I'm trying to use `get_post_meta` with the following hook, but it's always empty. I adjusted the priority to see if that would help, but no luck. Any ideas?

The post meta is definitely in the db after publish.

```
function some_function( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( ( $new_status == 'publish' ) && ( $old_status != 'publish' ) && ( $post->post_type == 'cpt' ) ) {

        // send admin notification
        $post_title = get_the_title( $post->ID ); 

        $message .= 'Name: ' . $post_title . '<br>';
        $message .= 'Email: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, '_email', true) . '<br>';

        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
        $headers[] = 'From: ' . get_option( 'blogname' ) . ' <' . get_option( 'admin_email' ) . '>';
        wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), $subject, $message, $headers );

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'some_function', 100, 3 );
```

The `post_title` is coming across in the email using the above, just no meta data.

If there's another hook or easier way, I'm all ears!

Comment: What's the return value of `get_post_meta`? I see you don't check the return value for errors

Comment: Well, in the email that is sent `get_post_meta` is blank

Comment: Then you have some debugging to do, e.g. it could be that the post meta doesn't exist, or that it does exist but it's blank, or false, or an empty string, or null, etc, etc. How are we to know if the value is never checked? Whatever it returns resolves to blank, but what exactly does it return?

Comment: Also how are these posts being published?

Comment: Tom, I'm hearing you my code SHOULD work. Is that accurate?

Comment: It returns an empty `array()` and adding post via Add New in the admin dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by looking at this post/answer:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134283/17126

Seems it can't be done, and I changed the `get_post_meta` line to:

```
$message .= 'Email: ' . sanitize_text_field($_POST['_email']) . '<br>';
```

Also, I could see the `$_POST` data coming in from post.php on submission over dev tools.

And finally, I changed my hook to `publish_cpt` which you can read more about here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

All good now!