# Is there an action that is called when a post is restored from the trash?

Tags: plugins, posts, admin, actions, trash

I'm looking at the wordpress list of actions and trying to find an action that is called when a post is restored from the trash but cannot find one. Does anyone know if it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple actions. Listed in order of appearance with their parameters:

- `untrash_post` - `(int) $post_id` // before restoring
- `transition_post_status` - `(string) $new_status, 'trash', (object) $post`
- `trash_to_{$new_status}` - `(object) $post` // useful to address a special trash to status action
- `untrash_post_comments` - `(int) $post_id` // before associated comments are untrashed
- `untrashed_post_comments` - `(int) $post_id` // after associated comments are untrashed
- `untrashed_post` - `(int) $post_id` // after restoring

Related answer with more statuses: [Execute function when post is published](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69802/73)

Comment: great answer. The particular one I was looking for was `untrashed_post`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in wp-includes/post.php and its called `untrashed_post`. For some reason wordpress chose not to include it on their action reference page at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference