# Can One Taxonomies Terms be Ordered by A Seperate Taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy, order, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I need some advice. I have a post type called "Movies" for example.

Inside Movies, I have two taxonomies: Genres and Ratings

Under Ratings my terms are 5 star, 4 star, 3 star, etc.

Under Genres terms are Classic, Romance, Comedy, etc.

Now, it gets tricky.

I have a page displaying a list of terms from the Taxonomy "Genres".  What I need to do is order the terms IN Genres by the rating taxonomy associated to each post in the post type. So I need 5 star Genres to be listed first and also ordered by the term having the most posts in it with the 5 star rating. After this, we will continue through the 4 star genres (in order of terms with most posts having 4 stars), onto 3 star, etc.

Also, if a term has the same # of post with X star rating as do other terms - then they can be ranked alphabetically.

Please let me know if there's any question and if I can clarify my burden here :-)

I am not a PHP or MySQL guru, so if this is very extensive. I may have to recruit some paid help to make something work.

Comment: This is definitely doable, but is going to take careful planning and coding. I think the best will be to do this sorting outside Wordpress with normal php. I won't be able to code to atleast Sunday (hopefully) again due to weekend responsibilities.

Comment: I have one question, any given post, does it only belongs to one term in the genres taxonomy and one term from the ratings taxonomy. What I mean is, no post can belong to two terms within the same taxonomy

Comment: Hi @Pieter Goosen, yes you are correct. Any given post should only belong to one term the genres taxonomy and one term on the star ratings taxonomy. It is possible that a post could belong to a parent and sub category in the genres category, but if that is a problem, we can probably just have the post associated with the child category. Please note that my example taxonomies here are just that - examples. My real taxonomies are named different, but the structure is the same as above. If you are willing to work on this for me, that would be excellent! Let me know what you can do :)

Comment: Question, if we do this, will we be able to retain my current page layout of terms? We can review my site beforehand.

Comment: You should be able to retain structures I believe. I would suggest that you use your exact names as it is quite important that I replicate the same structure when it come to sorting. It is quite straight forward sorting by rating if the terms are `5 star`, ` 4 star` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, this is doable, but we need to do careful planning as this is quite a heavy operation. On my test installation with a post count of just 13 posts, and 3 terms per taxonomy, the db is visited 20 times and the complete operation takes 0.03613 seconds. I have tried a couple of solutions, and this one is by far the fastest.

We will look at a workaround later to save on db calls and load time. Lets first see how the whole operation looks like and how it works

**PREPHASE**

Just a few notes before we start. This code is formulated to work based on the following

- Each post must have at least one term in both of the two taxonomies. If a post only has a term belonging to one of the two taxonomies, the code will fail
- On my test install, my post type is `cameras`, and my taxonomies are `brands` and `event_cat`, so be sure to change this accordingly

## HOW IT WORKS

**STEP 1**

Add your taxonomies in an array. This will be used to get all the terms associated with these two taxonomies

```
$taxonomies = [ 'event_cat', 'brands' ];
```

**STEP 2**

As stated in step 1, you need to get all the terms per taxonomy. [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) will be used to retrieve the terms. Empty terms will be skipped

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
```

**STEP 3**

The next step will be to get all the posts that belongs to the specific term. The term slug and taxonomy name will be used in a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to retrieve the posts. As you don't need any post data, you are just going to retrieve the post ID's

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cameras',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term->slug,
        ),
    ),
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

**STEP 4**

The post ID, term name and taxonomy name will now be used to create an array which will be used to create our list

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    $all_posts[$post][$taxonomy] = $term->name;
}
```

Your create array will look something like this

```
array(13) {
  [586]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "3 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
  }
  [582]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "3 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
  }
  [331]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "3 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
  }
  [329]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "3 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  [585]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "4 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
  }
  [583]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "4 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
  }
  [401]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "4 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
  }
  [330]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "4 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  [328]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "4 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  [587]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "5 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
  }
  [584]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "5 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
  }
  [581]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "5 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  [327]=>
  array(2) {
    ["event_cat"]=>
    string(6) "5 star"
    ["brands"]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
}
```

**STEP 5**

This new array will be the basis of the list that will be displayed. The first thing to do with this array is to use it to create a new array which will use the `ratings` terms as keys and the `genre` terms as the values

```
$group_ratings = [];
foreach ( $all_posts as $value ) {
    $group_ratings[$value['event_cat']][] = $value['brands'];
}
```

Your `$group_ratings` will now look like this

```
array(3) {
  ["3 star"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  ["4 star"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Classic"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
  ["5 star"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Romance"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Comedy"
  }
}
```

**STEP 6**

As you need the `5 star` term to appear first and `1 star` term last, we can use [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) to sort the array accordingly

```
krsort($group_ratings);
```

**STEP 7**

The array will now be split through a `foreach` loop. Each array value will now be counted with [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), then the resulting array will be sorted by array value and key value with [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). The sorting gave me a bit of a headache, so I had to go and look for some help. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571996/1908141) thanks to @theark

```
foreach ( $group_ratings as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key;
    $counted_values = array_count_values($value);
    array_multisort(array_values($counted_values), SORT_DESC, array_keys($counted_values), SORT_ASC, $counted_values);
//MORE TO COME
```

**STEP 8**

Finally the list can now be displayed. The array keys which holds the term names will be used as the term name, and the array value which holds the term post count will be used to display the post count for that particular term

```
foreach ( $counted_values as $counted_values_keys=>$counted_value ) {
    echo '<li>' . $counted_values_keys . ' (' . $counted_value . ') </li>';
}
```

As I said, this operation is quite heavy. To make this faster, you need to make use of [transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). What we are going to do is to store the result from `$group_ratings`. This is the variable that hold all the important information

This will significantly reduce the amount of db calls and load time. With the transient, only 2 db hits are recorded, and total time spend is only 0.00098 seconds. Just a note, I have set the transient expiry time for 24 hours, you can modify this as needed. A good time to set will be determined on how often do you add new posts

**ALL TOGETHER NOW!!**

Here is how the completed code looks like

```
if ( false === ( $group_ratings = get_transient( 'term_list' ) ) ) {
    $taxonomies = [ 'event_cat', 'brands' ];
    $all_posts = [];
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'cameras',
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $term->slug,
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $posts = get_posts( $args );

            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                $all_posts[$post][$taxonomy] = $term->name;
            }
            unset($post);
        }
    }

    $group_ratings = [];
    foreach ( $all_posts as $value ) {
        $group_ratings[$value['event_cat']][] = $value['brands'];
    }

    krsort($group_ratings);

    set_transient( 'term_list', $group_ratings, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}


echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $group_ratings as $key=>$value ) {
    echo $key;
    $counted_values = array_count_values($value);
    array_multisort(array_values($counted_values), SORT_DESC, array_keys($counted_values), SORT_ASC, $counted_values);

    foreach ( $counted_values as $counted_values_keys=>$counted_value ) {
        echo '<li>' . $counted_values_keys . ' (' . $counted_value . ') </li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

You will just need to style and modify it as needed. Here is how your list will look like

[image]

**BUT WAIT, WE'RE NOT DONE**

There are one last final step. The transient will only be updated if the transient expires which will be a problem if you publish new posts within during the time the transient is valid. You changes will only show after the transient expires and are updated.

What you need to do is to somehow delete the transient when a new post is published. This can be done using the [`transition_post_status`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=transition_post_status) hook as described here by @tosho in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69802/31545)

We need to slightly modify that code so that the transient only gets deleted when a new post is published and also just when a new post is published in the particular post type. This is how that code looks like (this goes into functions.php, and just remember to change the post type name)

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'a_new_post', 10, 3 );

function a_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

    if ( 'cameras' !== $post->post_type )
        return; // restrict the filter to a specific post type

    delete_transient( 'term_list' );
}
```

**WE'RE DONE!!!**

Comment: Hi pieter, I thank you for you dedicated time in helping me on this topic. I'm not savvy enough to have implemented this all myself so I hired the help of a developer and together we were able to accomplish it based on your recommendations! Thank you!