# WP-Automatic to run publish hooks

Tags: hooks, publish

Maybe there is someone who could help me with this plugin I use. I need it to run publish hooks, so plugin WP to buffer would work.

So now WP-Automatic, publishes content, but WP to Buffer doesn't know when it's published. I need to find place on WP-Automatic plugin where I could add publish hook and which would fire after each WP-Automatic's post publish.

Hook to fire is `do_action( 'publish_post', $post_id, $post );`

Please help me to locate these places where to add it, because WP-Automatic author is gone and I can't contact him in any way.

Comment: What is WP-Automatic, do you have a link? Furthermore [this should be helpful.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69772/execute-function-when-post-is-published)

Comment: have you tried `transition_post_status` hook? This could be helpful to ping buffer when a post has changed its statues to published. Or else, you could use the `{old_status}_to_{new_status}` hooks. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions